# \emph not working with TrueType font on XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, italic, emphasis

I am using a font package on my computer as both "roman" and "sans" font in such a way that `\setromanfont{Chaloult_Cond}  \setsansfont{Chaloult_Cond}` although it is a sans font. This makes great results and looks like I want. My problem is that `\emph` seems not to work with this font.

It is installed on my computer as 4 different fonts (there is a condensed version, a bold version, etc.), but there is no italic version of this font.

When I put another font as the roman font (eg. Constantia), `\emph`is working properly.

My question is then: How can I either specify a font to use when a text is emphasized or to force the rendering of a italicized version of the font (like Word would do when I activate italic)?

EDIT: Here is the code for `fontspec`

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font Chaloult_Cond does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
.................................................
\g_fontspec_family_Chaloult_Cond_int=\count126
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU" at 10.0pt
-> ^^9e^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ^^9b^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/B/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ¡^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Chaloult_Cond/B (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ^^9e^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/I/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ^^9b^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Chaloult_Cond/I (it probably doesn't exist).    
.................................................
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ¡^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/BI/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> ^^9e^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Chaloult_Cond/BI (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Chaloult_Cond(0)' created for font 'Chaloult_Cond' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Chaloult_Cond/ICU:mapping=tex-text;"
.................................................
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> ^^9b^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
    Requested font "Chaloult_Cond" at 10.0pt
 -> Å^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> Â^^C/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font Chaloult_Cond does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Chaloult_Cond(0)' created for font 'Chaloult_Cond' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.................................................
```

The error codes for font

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Chaloult_Cond(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/Chaloult_Cond(0)/m/n' instead on input line 10.

Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU:mapping=tex-text;" at 12.0pt
 -> ^^81^^E/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Chaloult_Cond(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/Chaloult_Cond(0)/m/n' instead on input line 20.

Requested font "Chaloult_Cond/ICU:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.95pt
-> i^^K/Windows/Fonts/CHALCN_.TTF
```

Comment: You should find in the log file what `fontspec` thinks about it and the associations to different fonts. Can you add the info? If there's no italic or slanted variant, you can fake it (see `fontspec`'s manual).

Comment: Add to your question, rather than in comments. Before the errors there should be a part where `fontspec` describes the font families it's defining.

Comment: I just added the `fontspec` lines

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/can-xelatex-generate-bold-and-italic-font-styles-for-typefaces-that-lack-them

Comment: It's working now. I didn't know the word "slant" to describe this formatting. I looked for italic and I hadn't found anything pertinent.